# CPU Temp i5-2400 and BSOD

Tags: windows-7, bsod, intel-core-i5

I'm getting random blue screens with error:

> 0x00000101 (0x0000000000000031, 0x0000000000000000,
>   0xfffff880009ea180, 0x0000000000000001)

It seems to have something to do with the cores not being able to get a process from a different core.

So I updated all the drives and looked through everything i could think of. Something I found said it might be hardware failure, so I thought I would look at core temp. Using SpeedFan it shows 88C, but the bios shows 38C and Core Temp 1.0 shows no higher then 34C for each core. Any idea why SpeedFan would display like that and a cure for my BSOD? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your CPU is overheating.  reapply FRESH thermal paste.

Answer (score 1):

According to *FaultWire* web site, the technical detail of this *clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor within the allocated time interval.Stop Code 0x00000101* is:

> An expected clock interrupt on a secondary processor, in a
>   multi-processor system, was not received within the allocated
>   interval. This can occurs when the processor is not responding or is
>   deadlocked.

which may explain the temperature reading as *88° C* by SpeedFan. The differences between this reading and the others may be the moment when the reading was done...

You say it's a *random* problem: if it's *really randon* there's big chance it's *hardware* **but** sometimes "random" problem are *not so random*... So don't jump to this conclusion too fast.

Keep an eye on what's running in your system with *Sysinternals Process Explorer* for example and keep your system load at a reasonable minimum (services, startup programs, etc.) Just to reduce the number of possible sources for this problem. Do this *"not responding"* or *"deadlock"* condtion comes from a driver, service, process **or** a defective hardware? Which process takes so much CPU Percentage and Time?

I suggest you to watch the temperatures with *HardwareInfo* to log the temperatures variations with the time and cross check this with the information in Process Explorer [CPU % and CPU Time].

http://www.hwinfo.com/

The FaultWire web site give some usual checkup procedures to troubleshoot this problem

http://www.faultwire.com

Hope this help. Let us know.

Comment: faultwire.com is apparently misconfigured and showing the standard apache landing page. :/

Answer (score 0):

This BSOD is a CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT error.

The most likely cause of this BSOD is misconfiguring the CPU by overclocking it. If you are overclocking your processor in the BIOS, disable it.

Comment: If I over clocked it, it was purely unintentional. I reset the CMOS and it ran for a few straight hours. thanks.